# Syncronise Workday Report with oracle database

Tags: web-services, soap, workday-api

is it possible to synchronise a Oracle database table with a Workday Report Web Service Export?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean Workday --> Oracle.  If you want the flow of information to go the other way around or be bi-directional, the answer is "yes, but not without a lot of work and custom development."

You're probably already delivering the data using an outbound EIB to an sftp landing zone somewhere.

At that point, it's just ETL as usual.  No different than if you extracted the data from any other application.  Probably the easiest solution would be to use an Oracle External Table on one of the formats recognized by Oracle (CSV is probably the simplest).